# How to Fix Missing Breakpoints View in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

For a couple weeks now, the Breakpoints View pane has gone missing and I cannot find a way to bring it back. Even the views menu in the left pane doesn't list it.

Any ideas how to restore this panel?

**Language being debugged:** TypeScript

**VS Code Version:** 1.48.0-insider

[image: Screenshot of missing Breakpoints Panel1]

No Breakpoints options available when right-clicking top pop-up, or any sub panel pop-up:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PROBLEM & SOLUTION**

The Breakpoints View was moved to its own Sidebar Icon which was not visible until a debugging session started. A bug has been filed: **[GitHub Microsoft/vscode Issue #102799](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102799)**.

**STEPS**

1. CMD+SHIFT+P to bring up the Show Command Palette
2. Enter and run "Focus on Breakpoints View"
3. Right-Click Breakpoints header, and choose "Reset Location"

*Thanks to @rioV8, @Arun205, and other forums/resources for the help working through this!!*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on 'Watch' tab and click on Breakpoints

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but there is no option in the pop-up menu. I have updated the original post to include a screenshot of this pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Right Click** on any View Header and see if the Breakpoint View is **Hidden**

If it is moved, find it in any Panel or other sidebar and **Right Click** View Header and choose **Reset Location**

Comment: Thank you. I do not see Breakpoint View anywhere, nor Reset Location. I've updated the original post with two new screenshots.

Comment: @n8sabes Look in the other sidebars and panels(terminals region)